# Difference between Fiware Scorpio Broker and Orion Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-scorpio, fiware-fogflow, fiware-stellio

Multiple brokers are available over Fiware,

1. Which have better performance Fiware Scorpio Broker and Orion Broker?
2. Does Orion Broker is NGSI-LD compliance and what is its roadmap to achieve the NGSI-LD specification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [FIWARE Catalogue](https://github.com/FIWARE/catalogue) currently contains four context brokers:

- Orion - NGSI-v2 only
- Orion-LD - mixed NGSI-LD and NGSI-v2 support
- Scorpio - NGSI-LD only
- Stellio - NGSI-LD only

Orion-LD is a fork from the original Orion repository and aims to be merged back at some point. It is the only context broker which can service both NGSI-v2 and NGSI-LD.

Scorpio and Stellio are pure NGSI-LD brokers which don't require the compromises of having to serve both syntaxes. Scorpio positions itself as the heavyweight broker, with a strong interest in federations. Stellio is somewhere in the middle between Scorpio and Orion.

All NGSI-LD brokers are trying to align to the ETSI standard, however new features are still being added (the latest ESTI update, the 1.3.1 specification was a couple of months ago). My understanding is that Orion complies with 95% of the 1.2.1 specification (excluding the temporal API). Scorpio is probably higher but some minor differences can be found within payloads

Running an ACID test [NGSI-LD Test-Suite](https://github.com/FIWARE/NGSI-LD_TestSuite/actions) returns the following for Scorpio:

```
Test Suites: 1 failed, 36 passed, 37 total
Tests:       1 failed, 168 passed, 169 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        38.595s
```

And the following for Orion-LD (where the majority of failed suites are for the optional temporal API which Orion-LD does not support directly)

```
Test Suites: 8 failed, 29 passed, 37 total
Tests:       22 failed, 147 passed, 169 total
Snapshots:   0 total
```

The roadmap for Orion-LD can be found [here](https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/blob/develop/doc/roadmap.md) within the GitHub repository.

Comment: Can you please approve the tag information of fiware-scorpio. it is created.